# Force google to just index rewrited urls

Tags: seo, url-rewriting

Let's think we have a website with a URL like `http://www.domain.com/webdesign/`
that rewrites `http://www.domain.com/?article=1`.

now when i search my keyword in Google, it will show up `http://www.domain.com/?article=1`
in search results, while there is no link to that in any page and all menus are linked to `http://www.domain.com/webdesign/` and i want that to be index.

***Is there anyway to solve this?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) or 301 redirects.

Canonical URL:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/webdesign/" />
```

That will tell Google to use that URL in its search results.